# Email conformation Otp not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an email confirmation functionality built this way :

**register :**

```
const OTP = generateOTP();
  const verificationToken = new VerificationToken({
    owner: newUser._id,
    token: OTP,
  });
  await verificationToken.save();
```

**verifyEmail:**

```
exports.verifyEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, otp } = req.body;
  if (!userId || !otp.trim())
    return sendError(res, "Invalid request, missing parameters!");
  if (!isValidObjectId(userId)) return sendError(res, "Invalid user ID");
  const user = await User.findById(userId);

  if (!user) return sendError(res, "User not found!");

  if (user.verified) return sendError(res, "This account is already verified");

  const token = await VerificationToken.findOne({ owner: user._id });
  if (!token) return sendError(res, "Token not found!");
  const match = await token.compareToken(otp);
  if (!match) return sendError(res, "Please provide a valid code");
  user.verified = true;
  await user.save();
  await VerificationToken.deleteOne({ _id: token._id });
  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: "Your email is verified",
    user: { username: user.username, email: user.email, id: user._id },
  });
};
```

- 

The problem I am facing is that sometimes, randomly, I encounter the error "token not found." I have tried to debug it multiple times, but the problem isn't reproducible. Any thoughts?

Comment: When it returns "token not found" does the token actually exist in the database?  Are you able to verify that it was added correctly?

Comment: well it doesnt exist when the probleme happens so i should probably add some verifications on here ?  "  await verificationToken.save() "

Comment: That's a good idea.  When saving log, the OTP and test that `VerificationToken.findOne({ owner: user._id })` finds a document with that same OTP immediately after saving.  Do you perhaps have a race between this verification and whatever process you have expiring the tokens?

Comment: "I don't think so. I even set the token to not expire, and the problem still occurred. However, I figured out that the issue is related to the creation of the verification token, as you mentioned earlier. The problem also occurs more often when there is some concurrency. I guess adding some verification in the creation step will fix the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.